# my xgboost model accuracy decreases after grid search with

Tags: xgboost, grid-search

I tried grid search for hyperparameter tuning in XGBoost classifier but the best accuracy is less than the accuracy without any tuning

```
// this is the code before the grid search
xg_cl = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', seed = 22)
xg_cl.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = xg_cl.predict(x_test)
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
[[11  1]
[ 1 26]]
0.9487179487179487
```

also, worth mentioning that the dataset shape is (195, 11) after PCA, and i am trying to classify whether a patient has a parkinsons disease or not.

```
// this is the grid search code
clf_xgb = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective = 'binary:logistic')
params__grid = {
    'n_estimators' : range(50,150,10),
    'max_depth': range(2, 12),
    'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.5,1,0.1),
    'reg_alpha' : np.arange(0,0.6,0.1),
    'reg_lambda' : np.arange(0,0.8,0.1)


}
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf_xgb, param_grid=params__grid, scoring = 'accuracy',
                            cv = 4 )
search.fit(x_train,y_train)

print('best score:/n',search.best_score_)
print('bestparams:/n' ,search.best_params_)

best score:
0.9038461538461539

best params:
{'colsample_bytree': 0.5,
     'max_depth': 7,
     'n_estimators': 50,
     'reg_alpha': 0.2,
     'reg_lambda': 0.1}
```

then I used these parameters to build and train a new classifier

```
clf_xgb_1 = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective = 'binary:logistic', max_depth = 7, n_estimators = 50, reg_alpha = 0.2 ,
                              reg_lambda = 0.1, colsample_bytree = 0.5 )
clf_xgb_1.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred_2 = clf_xgb_1.predict(x_test)
print('accuracy:/n', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_2))
print('confusion matrix:/n', metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_2))

accuracy:
0.8974358974358975

confusion matrix:
array([[ 9,  3],
       [ 1, 26]], dtype=int64)
```

How come my results are worse? I would expect that GridSearch would improve on the results.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: why is that?, it doesn't make sense to me, i thought the accuracy should improve after tuning the hyperparameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several points to take into account:

- First, it is possible that, in this case, the default XGBoost hyperparameters are a better combination that the ones your are passing through your *params__grid* combinations, you could check for it
- Although it does not explain your case, keep in mind that the *best_score* given by the GridSearchCV object is the ***Mean cross-validated score of the best_estimator*** ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)), it is, the mean test score across the k trainings over the k-folds, so it can maybe give you a more reliable score value (including also the standard deviation of the k scores)

Consider also that you do not need to retrain your model with the best params fron the grid search CV, since you can access the best model via *search.best_model*

Lastly, I would also recommend other hyperparameter tuning methods like the bayesian tuning, below a sample code gist using hyperopt (info about bayesian optimization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization)):

```
from hyperopt import hp
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK, Trials
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def return_model_scores(params, dataX, dataY, n_folds=5):
    import numpy as np

    defined_model, edp_cost_scores, histories = 
    evaluate_model_cost(dataX = dataX, dataY = dataY)   

return np.array(edp_cost_scores).mean()


param_space = {'max_depth' : hp.choice('max_depth', range(5, 30, 1)),
  'learning_rate' : hp.quniform('learning_rate', 0.01, 0.5, 0.01),
  'n_estimators' : hp.choice('n_estimators', range(20, 205, 5)),
  'gamma' : hp.quniform('gamma', 0, 0.50, 0.01),
  'min_child_weight' : hp.quniform('min_child_weight', 1, 10, 1),
  'subsample' : hp.quniform('subsample', 0.1, 1, 0.01),
  'colsample_bytree' : hp.quniform('colsample_bytree', 0.1, 1.0, 0.01),
  'scale_pos_weight': hp.uniform('scale_pos_weight', 0.2, 0.8)}

# Some variable 
dataX = X_train
dataY = y_train
assert len(X_train)==len(y_train)
n_folds=5

global best # global variable defined for convenience of this use case
best = 0
i = 0
def f(params):
    cost = return_model_scores(params, dataX, dataY, n_folds=5)  
    if i == 0:
        best = cost

    if cost < best:
        best = cost
    print('new best:', best, params)

    return {'loss': cost, 'status': STATUS_OK}

trials = Trials()
best = fmin(f, param_space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=10, trials=trials)

print ('best:')
print (best)
```

where *evaluate_model_cost* is the function you build for getting the cost values after evaluation:

```
def evaluate_model_cost(dataX, dataY):
    from tqdm import tqdm
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

    scores, histories = list(), list()
    # prepare cross validation
    kfold = KFold(10, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
    # enumerate splits
    k = 0
    for train_ix, test_ix in tqdm(kfold.split(dataX)):
        print('kfold {}'.format(k))

        # select rows for train and test
        trainX, trainY, testX, testY = dataX.iloc[train_ix], 
          dataY.iloc[train_ix], dataX.iloc[test_ix], dataY.iloc[test_ix]

        # fit model
        history = defined_model.fit(trainX, trainY, 
                                eval_metric= 'auc',
                                eval_set=[(testX, testY)])                               
    # evaluate model
    y_preds = defined_model.predict(testX[features_to_train_on])

    y_true_values = testY
    true_predicted_tuples = pd.DataFrame({'y_true': y_true_values, 'y_predicted': y_preds, 'days_till_slag': days_until_slag})
    true_predicted_tuples = true_predicted_tuples.reset_index(drop=True)
    #true positives, false positives and false negatives number
    tp_savings = 0

    first_tp_detected = False

    while first_tp_detected==False:
        for index in true_predicted_tuples.index:
            # TRUE POSITIVE condition:
            if ((true_predicted_tuples.iloc[index]['y_true']==1)&(true_predicted_tuples.iloc[index]['y_predicted']==1)):
                tp_savings += return_true_positive_savings(true_predicted_tuples.iloc[index]['days_till_slag'])
            break
        first_tp_detected = True

    fp_number = len(true_predicted_tuples[(true_predicted_tuples.y_true==0)&(true_predicted_tuples.y_predicted==1)])
    fn_number = len(true_predicted_tuples[(true_predicted_tuples.y_true==1)&(true_predicted_tuples.y_predicted==0)])

    final_cost = ((costs_dict['fp_cost'])*fp_number) + 
        ((costs_dict['fn_cost'])*fn_number) - tp_savings

    score = final_cost_custom_function

    print('score en evaluate_model_with_slag_days', score)

    # append scores
    scores.append(score)
    histories.append(history)

    k = k + 1

return defined_model, scores, histories
```

where *final_cost_custom_function* is your custom function of costs to minimize.
This might be a bit complicated case, if you want a very simple example of bayesian optimization, start with:

```
import pickle
import time
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK, Trials

def objective(x):
    return {
     'loss': x ** 2, 
     'status': STATUS_OK,
     # -- store other results like this
     'eval_time': time.time(),
     'other_stuff': {'type': None, 'value': [0, 1, 2]},
     # -- attachments are handled differently
     'attachments':
        {'time_module': pickle.dumps(time.time)}
     }
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(objective,
 space=hp.uniform('x', -3, 3),
 algo=tpe.suggest,
 max_evals=100,
 trials=trials)

print('with 100 trials: ', best)

trials = Trials()
best = fmin(objective, space=hp.uniform('x', -3, 3), algo=tpe.suggest,
 max_evals=1000, trials=trials)

print('with 1000 trials: ', best)
```

Comment: the search.best_estimator_ gives me the default XGBoost hyperparameters combination, i have two questions here, the first, the default classifier didn't enforce regularization so could it be that the default classifier is overfitting, the second is that the grid provided already contain the hyperparameters values obtained in search.best_estimator_, why the search.best_params_ wasn't the same as search.best_estimator ?, 
thanks for the reply, and  i am interested in an example about bayesian tuning.

Comment: you can find examples fo bayesian optimization in my former answer; about your questions, I find them also interesting to evaluate (I will try to reproduce it), but about the second one, I think it could also be because there are other hyperparameters you did not consider which, combined with another ones, give a different setting